# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist when searching

Tags: php, html, laravel

This issue shows up when searching for something -

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

But pagination is working fine and having a problem with just searching.

**Controller**

```
public function view(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request['search'] ?? "";
        if($search != ""){
            $customers = Customer::where('name', 'LIKE', "$search%")->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->get();
        }else{
            $customers = Customer::paginate(10);
        }

        $data = compact('customers','search');
        return view('customer-view')->with($data);
    }
```

**customer-view.blade.php**

```
    <form action="" class="col-6">
      <div class="mb-3 d-flex">
        <input type="search" name="search" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name or email" value="{{ $search }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-1">Search</button>
        <a href="{{ url('/customer/view') }}">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ms-1">Reset</button></a>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
      {{ $customers->links() }}
    </div>
```

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
 public function boot(){
    Paginator::defaultView('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-5');
 }
}
```

Comment: links will not work with             $customers = Customer::where('name', 'LIKE', "$search%")->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->get(); this
 query. the query need paginate always for links $customers = Customer::where('name', 'LIKE', "$search%")->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->paginate();

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your method like below and check again.

```
public function view(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request['search'] ?? "";
        if($search != ""){
            $customers = Customer::where('name', 'LIKE', "$search%")->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->paginate(10);
        }else{
            $customers = Customer::paginate(10);
        }

        $data = compact('customers','search');
        return view('customer-view')->with($data);
    }
```